# Possibility of defining one variable with multiple types based on a macro

Tags: c++, macros

I am wondering if it is possible to do:

```
class MyClass
  {
  public:
    MyClass();
    ...

#if defined USE_TYPE_ONE
    static TypeOne myVariable;
#else
    static TypeTwo myVariable;
#endif USE_TYPE_ONE
  };
```

The reason is that I have two classes, *TypeOne* & *TypeTwo*, with same function variables but different implementations and
I don't want to use macro in every place that *myVariable* is called.

**EDIT**

Thanks for prompt comments and answer. I have to mention that MyClass has been used a lot with different classes. That is why I would like to avoid template. Because even using template class with default template argument type, I have to use <> (change many other places) for other places that I use MyClass without need of TypeOne.

Comment: Yes this is possible. You should try compiling your code before asking if it is possible.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [class template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template).

Comment: @ChrisDrew That would probably be the right way to do this, unless he needs to store MyClass in a container.

Comment: @mascoj A class template can still derive from a common base class if that's what you mean.

Comment: Issue with using template: client code using `myVariable` would need to specify TypeOne or TypeTwo.  I think that's what OP wants to avoid.

Comment: @CrazyEddie you could easily provide a typedef or alias.

Comment: @ChrisDrew True, but he wouldn't be able to make a ```std::vector<MyClass>``` anymore. It would have to be either ```std::vector<MyClass<TypeOne>>``` or ```std::vector<MyClass<TypeTwo>>```. I love templates but they often ripple through already established software with unwanted consequences such as this.

Comment: Thanks for comments but I edited the question.

Comment: Then macro's or `std::conditional` is the way to go.

Comment: Do you want to use the same value of USE_TYPE_ONE throughout the program?  If so, then it's totally fine.  If you want to MyClass<TypeOne> in one place, and MyClass<TypeTwo> in another, then you have to use templates (the #define trick will cause Undefined Behaviour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a template as suggested but if you just need to switch between two types according to a condition and you have access to C++11 `<type_traits>` (otherwise consider updating your compiler), then you could use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
#include <type_traits>

constexpr bool USE_TYPE_ONE = true;

struct TypeOne { };
struct TypeTwo { };

class MyClass {
  using Type = std::conditional<USE_TYPE_ONE, TypeOne, TypeTwo>::type;
  static Type myVariable;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, you don't have to use macro's, you can use a templated class to achieve this:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
  {
  public:
    MyClass();

    static T myVariable;
  };
```

Then instantiate it how you like (for example for `int` types):

```
MyClass<int>::myVariable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't it be possible?  It's totally possible.  Of course you need to pass that preproc variable in the build somehow, and it'll be defined as that type for all code in the program...but it is indeed totally possible.